# How is the lighting panel of an Airbus A340 designed and how does it work?

Tags: airbus, cockpit, aircraft-lighting

I'm trying to simulate the light switch panel of an Airbus A340 with real electronics components for a model in scale (I'm doing the electronics lights with leds).

Taking a look at [this PDF *(page 129)*](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/tech_data/AC/Airbus-AC-A340-200-300-20140101.pdf), I would imagine that there are several switches for these lights. But when I searched on Google Images, I couldn't find a photo of this panel, only some diagrams of A320. I never saw one that I could identify.

**Question:**
How is the light switch panel and/or where can I find a picture or diagram?

**UPDATE 1:**

Is it something like this?
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm seeing that some switches have 2 or more points? For example NAV & LOGO, what means 1 and 2? Off, NAV or both?

And what about STROBE-BEACON, what does "AUTO" mean?

By the way, I couldn't find the "CARGO" light, and I think that "DOME" are the Landing Gear Bay, but what does BRT/DIM mean?

**UPDATE 3:**
I was reading this: 
[AIRBUS A340 - Flight Deck and System Briefing for Pilots](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CDMQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartcockpit.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fpath%3Ddocs%2F%26file%3DA340_Flight_Deck_and_Systems_Briefing_For_Pilots.pdf&ei=3VeNVaK8Oovu-AHxhpLwAw&usg=AFQjCNF7CD4wBskJQLZCVGdYbk6TxKCyKw&sig2=PzjMhSJo1iRY-UcFOkgvWA&bvm=bv.96782255,d.cWw&cad=rja)
But I couldn't find an image about the navigation panel.

Comment: I believe "dome" means cockpit ambient light; "brt" ("bright") means higher intensity and "dim" means lower intensity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nav and logo.

The logo light is a spotlight which illuminates the tail to show the airlines logo at night.  The Airbus A340 has two circuits for NAV/LOGO. Logo is an auto option when the landing gear is not compressed or the flaps are extended at 15º or more." in both positions, 1 and 2.

Dome is the cockpit ambient lighting.

Strobe on means the strobe is lit.  Auto means that the strobe is on when the landing gear is not compressed - i.e. it comes on just at the point of take-off and switches off on landing.  The point of having "on" as well is that some procedures require the strobe to be turned on just before entering the active runway and when leaving it.

Hope this helps.

Picture of the panel:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! And the distribution for airbus a340, is that? Where can I found a picture or diagram about that? thanks in advance!

Comment: @LeandroTupone Do you mean a wiring diagram?  I don't have those.

Comment: No no, like the image I post, a diagram on how there is the panel. Or a pic

Comment: Sorry for my vocabulary, I'm not an english native speaker

Comment: Actually I was reading that airbus a340 has two circuit for NAV/LOGO so that's why are 1 and 2. LOGO is an auto option "when the main gear struts are compressed or the flaps are extended at 15º or more." in both positions, 1 and 2

Comment: @LeandroTupone Please never apologise for your vocabulary.  The problem is mine to ask questions to clarify since your English is very much better than my Spanish.  It seems that I was wrong about the nav/logo and you have accurately answered your own question.

Comment: @LeandroTupone [This picture](http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/9/8/6/0461689.jpg) is high resolution so you can zoom in and see it it really looks.  Is this what you needed?

Comment: Simon, you rocks!!!! That was I was looking for!!! THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 6):

I found it, specifically for A340, page 11 of this document:
http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/FCOM_A340-Lights.html
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see the comments of the Simon answer, who post a very good photo of the panel !